# How to acces images which is not in App

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am working on an App, which contains a lot many images, and this is the reason of increasing build size and memory leaks, I have images in my App itself and reading it using plist.
Is there any other way to read/access images without putting all of them into the App.

Comment: From where do you want images from web, from phone gallery or from camera ?

Comment: From Web, I am using my own drawn images

Comment: You need internet to download it in your app, like janusfidel said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store the images in a remote server, then write the URL in a plist file , then you can use something like [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/) to download and display the images (SDWebImage will download and display the image by passing a url to it as argument). there are many open source framework out there, or you can code it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this way need internet access all the time, but I don't want to create a way which is dependent on internet.

Comment: not all the time, the framework I suggested will cache the image.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, make an XML or JSON of the names of all images. When your app starts you just first download that JSON (after parsing)and (first) show only name of the Image to the user. When user click on the name of the image, then go the detail view of that image and download the complete image. by this way you will be downloading only the required image. Which reduces the load of your application.

Comment: i will recomend looking into this project https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView/commits/master

Answer (score 0):

Yes above answer fit to your requirement. you can upload images on remote server then in application did finish launching or whenever you need download these images in device download directory and get each image path from.